# Expand the User Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I'm trying to expand the User Model with another Table (profile) to get a profile-picture, position, etc.

Can I override the `index()` function of the User Model to do that?

Current Model-Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'user_group'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74607121/edit) and include your code. Models in Laravel don't have an `index()` by default, so your question doesn't make any sense... Are you perhaps trying to setup a Relationship between your `User` model and a new `Profile` model?

Comment: well, edited the question & pasted the Model.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is setting up a relationship between the `User` Model and a new `Profile` Model. To do this you first need to create a Model `Profile` and it's associated Tabble `profiles`

`php artisan make:model Profile --migration`

In `database\migrations` there should be a file called something like that `2022_11_28_223831_create_profiles_table.php`

Now you need to add a foreign key which indicates to which User this profile belongs.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        // $table->string('path_to_picture')
        // user id
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Now in your User Model add the following function

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

And in your Profile Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Run `php artisan migrate` and everything should work as expected

If you want to test if the relationship works as expected create a new TestCase with

`php artisan make:test ProfileUserRelationTest`

In `tests\Feature\ProfileUserRelationTest.php`

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Profile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class ProfileUserRelationTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    public function test_the_relation_between_user_and_profile_works()
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'email' => 'jd@example.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('password'),
        ]);
        $profile = new Profile();
        $profile->user_id = $user->id;
        $profile->save();

        $this->assertEquals($user->id, $profile->user->id);
        $this->assertEquals($user->name, $profile->user->name);
        $this->assertEquals($profile->id, $user->profile->id);
    }
}
```

Now you can run `php artisan test` to see if everything works.

Be carefull **this will refresh your database!** So don't test in production.

Output should something like this

```
   PASS  Tests\Unit\ExampleTest
  ✓ that true is true

   PASS  Tests\Feature\ExampleTest
  ✓ the application returns a successful response

   PASS  Tests\Feature\ProfileUserRelationTest
  ✓ the relation between user and profile works

  Tests:  3 passed
  Time:   0.35s
```

Learn more about Relationships in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Learn more about migrations: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations

**Alternative**

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'email' => 'jd@example.com',
    'password' => Hash::make('password'),
]);

$user->profile()->create(...); // replace the ... with the things you want to insert you dont need to add the user_id since it will automatically added it. It will still work like the one above.
```